# How to return a list contains Object in sqlalchemy in python, is similar to List<OrderInfo> in java

Tags: java, python, mysql, sqlalchemy, tornado

i want to get a list which contains entire OrderInfo Object, for example, if i do this, it is result which the result i want to.

```
def find_all(self):
    result_list = []
    orderDao = DaoUtil.DaoGeneric()
    session = orderDao.getSession()
    try:
        for row in session.query(OrderInfo).all():
            result_list.append({
                'id':row.id,
                'name': row.name,
                'age': row.age,
                 'create_time': row.create_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                 'update_time': row.update_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                    'version': row.version
                })
            session.commit()
    except Exception, e:
         print e
         session.rollback()
    return  result_list
```

but i want to a list which contains OrderInfo object from the query, because the result which the query return have other columns (the simple list of all DeclarativeBase's instances.) except OrderInfo{id,name,age,create_time,update_time,version}, the query do not return OrderInfo object directly. the following which i want to:

```
def find_all(self):
    result_list = []
    orderDao = DaoUtil.DaoGeneric()
    session = orderDao.getSession()
        try:
            for row in session.query(OrderInfo).all():
                result_list.append(row.orderInfo) // if the row has a property for orderInfo Object, because the result which java can achieve , the example  for java is :   List<OrderInfo> orderList = session.query(); please help to achieve it


            session.commit()
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        session.rollback()
    return  result_list
```

beacause i use sqlalchemy in python just now,  i am not very sure. How to get a list which contains OrderInfo Object from query in sqlalchemy

Comment: `session.query(OrderInfo).all()` is a list of `OrderInfo` objects.

Comment: _decl_class_registry
_sa_class_manager
_sa_instance_state
metadata
query
id
name
age
create_time
update_time
version

Comment: You want a list of `OrderInfo` objects but you are surprised that each one has attributes that are on `OrderInfo` objects?? If this were Java, would you be surprised that your `OrderInfo` objects have `toString` on them?

Comment: @univerio, In fact,   i want to get OrderInfo object that from query result,  but  the result of query which includes  many excess columns (_decl_class_registry,       
_sa_class_manager,      
_sa_instance_state,    
metadata,       
query)  for me, i only want to (id,name,age,create_time,update_time,version ) which include a property of query,  The other what do not i want to get.

Comment: I'm afraid you're gonna have to fix your English. You are asking something different in your title (a `List<OrderInfo>` in Java terms) compared to your comments (a `List<Dictionary<String, Object>>`). Please edit your question if you want to clarify it; do not leave comments as answers.

Comment: i understand what you mean, i think about myself first,  my english is poor,  i do not express clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the answer which i want to get:

```
   def find_all(self):
        result_list = []
        orderDao = DaoUtil.DaoGeneric()
        session = orderDao.getSession()
        try:
            for row in session.query(OrderInfo).all():
                result_list.append(DictUtil.object_as_dict(row))
            session.commit()
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            session.rollback()
        return result_list


def object_as_dict(obj):
    result = {instance.key: getattr(obj, instance.key)  for instance in inspect(obj).mapper.column_attrs}
    print result
    return result
```

output :

```
[
{'updateTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 15, 13, 56, 16), 'bankName': u'ICBC', 'bankNo': u'6228480666622220011', 'createTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 15, 13, 56, 16), u'version': 0, u'id': 1}, 
{'updateTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 15, 13, 57, 40), 'bankName': u'ICBC', 'bankNo': u'6228480666622220011', 'createTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 15, 13, 57, 40), u'version': 0, u'id': 2}, 
{'updateTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 15, 13, 58), 'bankName': u'ICBC', 'bankNo': u'6228480666622220011', 'createTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 15, 13, 58), u'version': 0, u'id': 3}
]
```